# AngularJs accessing attribute difference, via linking and scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Can anyone explain whats the difference between accessing directive attribute from the scope as in :

```
scope: { someVar: '=' }
```

vs

```
link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
  attr.someVar
}
```

It seems somehow both accomplish the same thing.

Comment: the first one creates a new isolated scope (which is always recommended when you are creating components as it will not polute parent scope ) and the second one does not create a scope you are just referring to the attribute value passed into the directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AngularJS ng.$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile):

> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute... Any changes to parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in localModel will reflect in parentModel.

In other words, this creates a watch on the attribute, causing changes to the model in either the parent scope or the directive scope to be reflected in the other.

Referencing the attribute merely returns a string. Thus if you had a directive `foo` and your HTML looked like

```
<foo some-var="bar"></foo>
```

In your link function, `attr.someVar` would be the string literal `"bar"`. You can evaluate `bar` in the scope by calling `scope.$eval(attr.someVar)` (or `scope.$parent.$eval(attr.someVar)` if the directive has an isolate scope) at any time, but it is not done for you.